# Activesupport error while installing rails in jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby, activesupport

I installed jRuby using rvm. It's version is jruby-1.6.7.2 [ i386 ].
Now I am trying to install rails on top of it.
But I am getting following error

> ERROR:  Error installing rails:   activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.

I am using following command to install rails which I found in many answers on so itself.

> jruby -S gem install rails --pre --no-rdoc --no-ri

I also tried passing --1.9 option to jruby so that it can use ruby 1.9 interpreter. But that also not working.

> jruby --1.9.3 -S gem install rails

My RVM list is as follows :

rvm rubies

```
 => jruby-1.6.7.2 [ i386 ]
    ruby-1.8.7-p358 [ i686 ]
  * ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ] 
    ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ i686 ]
```

Please guide me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to update your JRuby version?

Alternatively, try set this shell variable:

```
export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
```

...then re-execute your `gem install rails` command.